# Rails4-carrierwave specifying different bucket for different models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I am using carrierwave to upload images to google store. Is there some way to specify different buckets for different models. I tried keeping

```
config.fog_directory = ''
```

in carrierwave.rb and then writing the name of buckets in store_dir in individual uploaders file but that gave following error:-

> [fog][WARNING] fog: the specified google storage bucket name () is not a valid dns name.  See: https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/bucketnaming
>   Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 815ms (ActiveRecord: 1.1ms)
>
> Excon::Errors::SocketError (getaddrinfo: No address associated with hostname >(SocketError)):

Comment: What kind of error it gave? It will help understanding the problem if you include the error and possibly stack trace.

Comment: I included the error

Comment: As the error states, either you are setting the bucket name to be () or " ", which is not valid bucket name. Check how you are setting it.

Comment: If I set the bucket name in carrierwave.rb, I won't be able to use different buckets for different models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer finally on carrierwave wiki page.https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3a-Define-different-storage-configuration-for-each-Uploader.